# Performance of update vs if exists then update

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql

I am wondering if there is a performance difference for sql between

```
update dbo.table
set x = 1
where x is null
```

and

```
if exists (select 1
           from dbo.table t
           where t.x is null)
begin
    update dbo.table
    set x = 1
    where x is null
end
```

in case there are **no** null values found for x.

I wasn't able to find an answer for this so I hope anyone can clear this up for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct. The where conditions in `if exists` and `update` statements in the second code snippet are the same: `from dbo.table t where t.x is null` so I do not expect any significant speed difference in case there are no null values found for x.